# Showing a Google Map in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a JQuery Mobile application. I want this application to include a Google map in it. I was basing my implementation on the jquery-ui-map plugin. They have sample code available at http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#basic_map.

Even with that example, I still can't get a map to appear. I feel like I'm using the most basic code. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? My code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/scripts/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="result" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>My App</h1></div>

        <div data-role="content">
          <div id="resultMap" style="height:200px; width:200px; background-color:Lime;">   
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#result").live("pageshow", function () {
            $("#resultMap").gmap();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: map() instead of gmap()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I'm doing it like this:

```
var home = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);

$('#directions_map').live("pageshow", function() {
    $('#map_canvas_1').gmap('refresh');
    });

$('#directions_map').live("pagecreate", function() {
    $('#map_canvas_1').gmap({'center': home, 'zoom':17 });
    $('#map_canvas_1').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': home, 'animation' : google.maps.Animation.DROP } );
    });
```

So please try:
- create the gmap on pagecreate
- only refresh on pageshow
- the marker is a bonus ;-)

let me know if this does the trick. It's from a working example of mine, so it should be ok. I think it's important you set up the gmap ahead of pageshow. If you think of JQM as a stage... pageshow would be right before lifting the curtain. Maybe too late for Google Magic. Pagecreate seems better...

Comment: No luck. Is there a restriction that you cannot run it under localhost? This is so bizarre. Do you have a full .html file available somewhere? I just can't believe this doesn't work. Its pretty straightforward. BTW: Thank you for your help.

Comment: probably localhost, but I'm no expert. check my page from which I copied the above: http://www.franckreich.de/5/about.html - I'll remove the link again later.

Comment: Thanks frequent. I downloaded your code and ran it from localhost. Interestingly enough, it worked! I'm going to keep digging and try to identify why my code isn't work. I appreciate you're help. I'll post another comment here once (if) I figure out why my other code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

[jquery-mobile with google maps](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html)

I found it fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Yeah. I saw that. That's where my link points to. Yet, my code doesn't work. I can't figure out what is missing. I've tried, retried from scratch without any luck. The sample they show works in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't get the basic example from the jQuery UI Maps to work on the first try.  After fiddling with the example in the "demos" folder of the `jquery-ui-map-3.0-rc` directory, I preened out all of the unnecessary html and javascript to dispaly a very basic map.  Unfortunately the website has code snippets, rather than a full, working but minimalistic example.

You'll have to check that the references to the links and scripts are correct.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>Example with Google maps and jQuery - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map_canvas" class="map rounded"></div>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../ui/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 10, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                        var self = this;
                        self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {
                            self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello World!' }, this);
                        }); 
                    }});
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```